# Hash functions for dynamic types at runtime?

Tags: database, dynamic, hash, hashmap, hashcode

We are building a relational database management system (RDBMS) in C++ and need a way to hash data of a variety of types in tables when they are created at runtime. For example, we need to be able to hash a tuple of data (e.g. "Jack", 20, "Male") given a primary key of unknown type(s) (e.g. int, 2 strings, etc.). Any tips on how to approach this? Thanks!